# AgglomerativeClustering on precomputed Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, sparse-matrix, hierarchical-clustering

In my current approach, I have

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame([[0.8, 0. , 3. ],
       [1. , 1. , 2. ],
       [0.3, 3. , 4. ]], columns=['dist', 'v1', 'v2'])
sparseD = csr_matrix((1-s['dist'], (s['v1'].values, s['v2'].values)), shape=(N, N))
agg = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, affinity='precomputed', linkage='complete', distance_threshold=.25)
agg.fit_predict(sparseD)
```

The last line raises

```
TypeError: cannot take a sparse matrix.
```

If I cast the data `toarray`, the code works and produces the expected output, but uses a lot of memory and is slow: on the real data size: 61K x 61K.

I am wondering if there is another library (or scikit API) that can do the same linkage clustering on a precomputed, sparse Distance matrix -- if there were no entry for a given (element1, element2) pair, the API would not link them and everything else would be the same.

Comment: Who or what raises the `TypeError`?  You won't get much help if you are stingy with the debugging information.

Comment: Sorry! The last line raises `TypeError`

Comment: There are sklearn operations that do work with sparse matrices.  More than most packages.  Apparently this isn't one of those.  Function docs should be clear on the matter.

Comment: Totally! My question is whether there is a similar function that works on sparse matrices.

Comment: @Sam Sheleifer, did you ever find out the answer. I am after the same issue, but no solution so far... Thank you.